# unable to make api request with http ruby gem

Tags: ruby, api, http, curl, request

I am trying to translate a curl request that works in the terminal for me into ruby code using the `http` gem.

This is the curl request that gives me back the valid json I want:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'api_key: somekey' --header 'authtoken: sometoken' 'https://cdn.domain.io/v3/content_types/shirts/entries?environment=dev'
```

With the [http gem](https://github.com/httprb/http/) I try to do this in my ruby script:

```
HTTP.headers(:Accept => "application/json", :api_key => 'somekey', :authtoken => 'sometoken').get("https://cdn.domain.io/v3/content_types/shirts/entries", :params => { :environment => 'dev'}).body.readpartial
```

And this gives my back `"api_key":["is not valid."]}` error from the server

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?

Comment: maybe make different `.header(...)` calls (chain them) like `.headers(accept: "application/json").headers(api_key: 'somekey')....` ? I dont know the http gem; if this apporach works, probably worth signing a bug report on github.

Comment: Tried chaining like you said. Didn't work

Comment: Didn't get error with WEBrick v1.3.1, http v2.1.0 and Rails v4.2.5. Maybe post more information about how to reproduce?

Comment: @AlexanderMorozov - you made a successful request with the gem?

Comment: @Amit Erandole - Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) seems to be working out well:

```
require "typhoeus"
require 'multi_json'
require "awesome_print"

response = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "https://api.domain.io/v3/content_types/shirts/entries?environment=dev",
  headers: { api_key: "somekey", access_token: "sometoken",
  accept_encoding: "gzip" }
).run

# puts response.body
begin
  ap MultiJson.load(response.body, :symbolize_keys => true)
rescue MultiJson::ParseError => exception
  p exception.data # => "{invalid json}"
  p exception.cause # => JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at '{invalid json}'
end
```